# Php writing edited script file content cause extra line breaks

Tags: php, file, filesystems, fopen

In a multilingual site i have two php files that contains php constants.

### Like

define('EMAIL', 'Email');
define('GENDER', 'Gender');
.
.

### .

I provide editing of these files from admin side using a textarea in form. print full file in textarea.
When ever admin Update the files it contribute redirection issue, means after inclusion of this file header() function fails reporting a non white space character above.

### I checked the php file after editing, and it contain a lot of extra space between each php statment as follow,

define('EMAIL', 'Email');

define('GENDER', 'Gender');

### define('NAME', 'name');

Also a long single line breaks into many lines like.

**define('SENTENCE', 'this is a long sentence that
breaks into many lines according to width of text area as i noted');**

So this also contribute error as it must be in single line

I am sure these extra spaces and line breaks are cause of all issues. I am using this code in printing between textarea:

```
<textarea  style="width: 664px; height: 353px;" id="edit_file" name="edit_file"><?php
$file = fopen("../en.php", "r") or exit("Unable to open file!");
//Output a line of the file until the end is reached
while(!feof($file))
  {
echo fgets($file);
  }
fclose($file);
?> </textarea>
```

and for saving file:

```
if(isset($_POST['btn']) && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST' && !empty($_POST['btn'])){
if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) {
$filedata = stripslashes($_POST['edit_file']);
}
$filedata=str_replace(array("<br />'",'\n'),array("",''),$filedata);
$size=strlen($filedata);
$file = fopen("../en.php", "w") or exit("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($file,"$filedata",$size);
fclose($file);
}
```

Comment: what is the problem OR error, post this...

Comment: error or ISSUE: after writing textarae contents into file, if i open file in any texteditor or dreamweaver it show many line between two php statments, i want to avoid this, and want each statement on consecutive lines, extra lines between 2 php statements are contributed by HTML textarea or in printing file content to textarea.

Comment: @Yogesh Suthar, these extra lines or stamnets breakes ( long statements breaks into 2 or 3 lines) cause php header redirection failure.

Comment: means you are creating `php` file from content of textarea??

Comment: yes, i open a file let say abc.php and show contents in textarea, after form submission i write textarea content to abc.php file, file is already exist. just reading and writing.

Answer (score 3):

There is 1 unexpected quote and \n cannot be put inside simple quotes :

```
$filedata=str_replace(array("<br />'",'\n'),array("",''),$filedata);
```

Replace by :

```
$filedata=str_replace(array("<br />","\n"),array("",''),$filedata);
```

Comment: @Ninsuo +1 thanks for your help. Yes, unexpected single quote was 1 reason, and i apply your suggested solution it works for local and i will accept your answer after executing on linux server.

Comment: I checked on server, now editing don't contribute line breaks and this code worked perfectly. But After editing the php file, the consumer script failed in redirecting to any other page. Please suggest.

Comment: You are probably using `header()` after outputing something (like a form or such) but that's forbidden when output buffering is not configured properly. At the very top of your script, put `ob_start();` and at the end of your script, put `ob_end_flush();`.